# about organizing threads in cuda

Tags: c++, cuda

general question: the number of threads must be equal to the size of the elements i want to deal with? exmaple: if i have matrix M[a][b]. i must allocate (aXb) threads or i can allocate more threads than i need(more than ab)? because the thread that will focus on element aXb+1 will throw us out, doesnt he? or the solution is to put a condition(only if in range(ab))?

specific question: let be M[x][y] matrix with x rows and y columns. consider that 1000 <= x <= 300000 and y <= 100. how can i organize the threads in that way that it will be general for each input for x and y. i want that each thread will focus on one element in the matrix. CC = 2.1 thanks!

Comment: You can allocate more or you can even allocate less.  Either approach can be made to work.  If you allocate more threads than are needed, your kernel should include a conditional test to make sure each thread is operating on valid data.  If you allocate less threads than needed, your kernel should include [a loop of some sort](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) to cover all the data items.

Answer (score 1):

General answer: It depends on a problem.

In most cases natural one-to-one mapping of the problem to the grid of threads is fine to start with, but what you want to keep in mind is:

1. Achieving high occupancy.
2. Maximizing GPU resources usage and memory throughput.
3. Working with valid data.

Sometimes it may require using single thread to process many elements or many threads to process single element.
For instance, you can imagine an series of independent operations A,B and C that need to be applied on array of elements. You could run three different kernels, but it might be better choice to allocate the grid to contain three times more threads than there is elements and distinguish operations by one of the dimensions of the grid (or anything else). On the other side - you might have a problem that could use maximizing the usage of shared memory (e.g transforming the image) - you could use block of 16 threads to process 5x5 image window where each thread would calculate some statistics of each 2x2 slice.

The choice is yours - the best advice is not always go with the obvious. Try different approaches and choose what works best.